# Conditional ClassName in Router in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom, jss

I have a router in my react app and i wanted to apply the `classes.root` on specific routes only.
However the code below doesn't work since it is inside the `<Switch>`. As you can see in my code, that i wanted to apply the `classes.root` only on the `Login` and `Signup`.
Pls check my code below:

```
function Routes() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Router>
      <Suspense fallback={<h3>Loading...</h3>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/goto" component={GoTo} />
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <Route path="/signin" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          </div>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Private} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how `Route` is defined from using `component` property to using `render` property. I have not included passing the props to `Login` component, I just showed how you can use the `classes`.

If necessary, then you should use `<Login {...props}/>`

```
<Route path="/signin" component={Login} />
```

to this

```
   <Route path="/signin" render={props => {
     return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Login/>
      </div>
    )
   }}
  />
```

Comment: is passing the props more recommended?

Comment: it's how you use them. if you dont need them, you dont pass them :)